# Is there a way to make the speaker silent while the headphone-jack keeps working? 12.04LTS

Tags: sound, headphones, soundcard

The PC I am working on is in a loud environment. If I need sound, I use the headphone. On my own account this is easy: I mute the speaker in the sound-setting. I am not the only user, others use the Guest-session. And that's what this question about:

Is it possible to turn off the speaker by default on a guest-session AND leave the headphone-output working?

If yes, how can I fix it?

I tried to loosen the speaker (hardware) connection but it is soldered to the mainboard.

The soundcard on the PC is:

```
HDA Intel at 0xfea78000 irq 44

/proc/asound/pcm ───────────────────────────┐

│00-00: ALC662 rev1 Analog : ALC662 rev1 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1│

│00-02: ALC662 rev1 Analog : ALC662 rev1 Analog : capture 1   

Ubuntu 12.04LTS is running on the system, my account has all the (admin) rights
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `alsamixer` to accomplish this.

[image: Alsamixer Screenshot]

Unfortunately the options you need are not in my screenshot, but if you have headphone sense option (or something similar), unmute that, and if possible, turn the speakers to off. This way, the speakers will be off by default, but the headphones will be enabled.